# Program returns -1073741819 when using strcat in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

This is the whole function. Basically what I was trying to do is to erase some words from a sentence. I experience when the program reaches the first strcat line.

I really have no clue, what is the problem here? Did I misuse the pointers?

EDIT: I try this:

```
   void reset_array(char* word,int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        word[i] = 0;
}

void change_sentence(char* new_sentence, char* sentence, int n)
{
    while (new_sentence!=EMPTY)
    {
        *sentence = *new_sentence;
        sentence++; new_sentence++;
    }
}

void delete_words(char * words[], int n, char * sentence) 
{
    char* sen_copy = sentence; bool first = true;
    char* new_sentence = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(sentence)+1);
    reset_array(new_sentence, strlen(sentence) + 1);
    char* new_sentence_copy = new_sentence;
    while (*sen_copy)
    {
        char current_word[MAX_LEN];
        reset_array(current_word,MAX_LEN);
        int i = 0;
        while (*sen_copy && *sen_copy != WORD_SEPERATOR)
        {
            current_word[i] = *sen_copy;
            i++;
            sen_copy++;
        }
        if (!is_string_in_array(words, n, current_word))
        {
            if (!first)
            {
                *new_sentence_copy = WORD_SEPERATOR;
                new_sentence_copy++;
            }
            int count = 0;
            while (count < i)
            {
                *new_sentence_copy = current_word[count];
                count++;
                new_sentence_copy++;
            }
            first = false;
        }
        if (*sen_copy == WORD_SEPERATOR)
            sen_copy++;
    }
    printf("Hi");
    change_sentence(new_sentence, sentence, strlen(sentence) + 1);
    free(new_sentence);
}
```

I get the same error code.

What causes the error now? Am I not allowed to change sentence? I thought you could do it if it's an array.

Comment: `new_empty_string` is pointing to a string literal, which you cannot modify. And in general, you should take a look at dynamic memory management and string manipulation as there are other issues related in the code.

Comment: You pass `cptr` to `strcat` but it isn't pointing to a string, it points to `char a`

Comment: And even if you could modify it, it has room for 0 characters.

Comment: sentence = empty_string doesnt do much outside the function. first of all you setting it to point to a local value so what sentence points to will be lost once leaving the function. second in order to change what a pointer points to, you need to pass the address of the pointer.

Comment: FYI -107.... is hex 0XC0000005. Which is windows speak for access violation. In this case you have tried to write to read only memory

Comment: i would suggest you split the sentence in words using `strtok` creating an array of those words, then go through them and remove the words you dont want, thereafter put whatever is left in that array into a new sentence.

Comment: It's not great to edit your question so that it suddenly becomes a different question and the previous responses make no sense...

Comment: I apologise. I'll add the original program in a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard, § 6.7.9: *Initialization*:

> The declaration `char *p = "abc";` defines p with type ‘‘pointer to char’’ and initializes it to point to an object with type ‘‘array of char’’ with length 4 whose elements are initialized with a character string literal. **If an attempt is made to use p to modify the contents of the array, the behavior is undefined**.

Emphasis mine.

You cannot assign to `new_empty_string` after it is declared. Neither the assignment operator, `=`, nor making it the destination parameter in `strcat` will work. Your options:

1. Declare `new_empty_string` as an array of type `char []`, where the length is sufficient to hold the value(s) you expect
2. Allocate sufficient memory for `new_empty_string` with `malloc` or related functions, and `free` the memory when you are done using it.

Comment: I tried char* new_sentence = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(sentence)+1); However there is a problem, because I need to print sentence itself in the main (we were given the main and have to use it), and I can't just write sentence=new_sentence in the function. Is my only option working only sentence itself in the function?

Comment: @איתןלוי Heap memory (i.e. memory allocated with `malloc`-family functions) persists beyond the lifetime of its scope, so long as you have a pointer to it.